# Multiprocessing or Multithreading for plugin architecture in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, plugins

I'm trying to implement a plugin architecture in Python.

I've started writing it using the `Threading` module where each plugin is a thread which I invoke using the `Thread.start()` method (since all plugins subclass `BasePlugin` which subclasses `Thread`). However I've just come across the `multiprocessing` module.

I'm currently wondering if I should switch to the `multiprocessing` module and share data using shared memory / Pipes etc...

I'd like to get other's opinions on this.

The plugin architecture I've been working on works as follows:

An event is received by the `Plugin Manager`. The `Plugin Manager` checks for all the plugins who've subscribed to that type of event. It activates them and sends them the event object (since it holds additional information). If one of the plugins is already active there is no need to spawn it (just send the event object to it).

In addition there are a few resources which belong only to one plugin at any point in time. Each plugin can request the resource (I'm not worrying about any race condition here since there won't be that many plugins active at once).

Answer (score 1):

Threads share memory with the primary process and each other. For example you can have a list that is available to all threads. An item appended to a list can be seen by other threads. But you have to be careful. You have to understand which operations on data structures are thread safe and which are not. What happens to the behaviour of your program when two threads are checking for the existence of a key in a dictionary and then writing to it?

Multiple processes do not share memory. The new process that you start gets a copy of the memory at the point where it was spawned.

Threads use less resources. But can be hard to reason about. On the other hand communication between processes is tricky. And you can't just access an arbitrary Python data structure. Which it sounds like you want to be able to do.

A badly written plugin, if it was in a thread, could crash your whole program. Whereas if it was in a separate process this wouldn't happen. Maybe that's a consideration?

Comment: "A badly written plugin, if it was in a thread, could crash your whole program" - You're right. Which is why I'm giving anyone who wants to write plugins (mainly me) a clean API so nothing bad will happen.

Comment: Excellent! Though remember that a thread has complete access. So if I was writing a plugin and decided to replace some central data structure with an empty string, then I could do that. But if this plugin system is only going to be used internally then I guess that's a moot point.